# Make last cell in UICollectionView fill width

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

In my `UICollectionView`, the last cell `indexPath` is 10. I want the last cell to fill the width. Now there are 2 cells each line, but I want the last cell to fill the whole width. This is what I have tried;

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let width = (view.frame.size.width - 40) / 2

    if indexPath.item == 10 {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat(100))
    }
    return CGSize(width: width, height: 100)
}
```

When I run the app and press the last cell, this output run:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
}
```

But somehow, this doesn't do anything. Any tips please?

Comment: Do you actually have 11 items in the collection view? What width is being used by the 11th cell?

Comment: @rmaddy I am using `didSelectItemAt`, and when I tapped the last cell, it gave me output `You selected cell #10!`. All the cell's width is equal to this: `let width = (view.frame.size.width - 40) / 2 `

Comment: You didn't answer my first question. I don't know how your are printing so it's still unclear whether you actually have 10 or 11 items in the table view. Remember, `indexPath.item` is 0-based.

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry, updated my question now with the printing also. Also tried changing to `if indexPath.item == 4 {` but it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by myself. I forgot to add the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.